# How to call library functions in shellcode

Tags: windows, 64-bit, nasm, shellcode

I want to generate shellcode using the following NASM code:

```
global _start
extern exit

section .text
_start:
    xor     rcx, rcx
    or      rcx, 10
    call    exit
```

The problem here is that I cannot use this because the address of `exit` function cannot be hard coded. So, how do I go about using library functions without having to re-implement them using system calls?

One way that I can think of, is to retrieve the address of `exit` function in a pre-processing program using `GetProcAddress` and substitute it in the shellcode at the appropriate place.

However, this method does not generate shellcode that can be run as it is. I'm sure there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on writing shellcode, but you could try to find the import address table (IAT) of your target program and use the stored function pointers to call windows functions.
Note that you would be limited to the functions the target program uses.
Also you would have to let your shellcode calculate IAT's position relative to the process's base address due to relocations. Of course you could rely on Windows not relocating, but this might result in errors in a few cases.
Another issue is that you would have to find the target process's base address from outside.
A totally different attempt would be using syscalls, but they are really hard to use, not talking about the danger using them.

Information on PE file structure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx